# Dynamic SQL Case statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that is called `DefaultCountries`.

It contains the following columns:

- CountryID INT
- DefaultCountryID INT
- CountryRank INT

I have 29 different countries with varying data for each country.  For example:

CountryID of 1 has 2 records:

[image: CountryID1]

CountryID of 7 has 3 records

[image: CountryID7]

I have a table variable `@CountryData` that I'm trying to join to that currently has data for CountryIDs 1 and 10.

[image: Example Table]

I would like to be able to match up to the `DefaultCountryID` found in the `DefaultCountries` table. So if I pass in `CountryID = 1`, I could do something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 DefaultCountryID 
WHERE CountryID = 1     -- that is my simple case.
```

Where I'm having an issue is where there are more than 2+ rows. As in my example for `CountryID = 7`. Basically I want to have something where if there is no records in my table that I'm trying to join to with the 1st record (`CountryRank = 1`) then I would like it to search for the next record.

So searching for `CountryID = 7`, then if nothing, then `CountryID = 10` (so on and so forth).

I've tried different variations of this LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT * 
FROM @CountryData cd
LEFT JOIN DefaultCountries dc ON dc.defaultCountryid = cd.CountryID
                              AND cd.CountryID = 7
```

But this just brings back all the data (1 & 10).  Do I have to use a loop to do this the way I'm describing?  I thought about a CASE statement as well, but since I could have more than 2+ in the `DefaultCountries` table I'm not sure how I could keep searching.

I tried doing an IN statement, but I have 2 issues there. I can't do an order by in the IN statement as I get the following message:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET
>   or FOR XML is also specified.

And even if there is a way to make sure I'm searching in the order I want using an IN statement, I want to make sure it stops searching on the 1st one it finds.  So to expand on my example, if table (@CountryData) table now contains records where CountryID = 7 and CountryID = 10 I only want to return the records where CountryID = 7.

Comment: Why not just join it on where rank = 1? Maybe i'm missing something here. Would there not always be a rank = 1 for each country?

Comment: @scsimon - there would always be a rank = 1 on the DefaultCountries table.

Comment: You might have a look at `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ...) AS Nr`. Usually such things can be solved with a `CTE` numbering the rows after a sorting clause you define in `OVER()`. The final `SELECT` uses a filter on `WHERE Nr=1`

Answer (score 1):

If i'm following you right you can just use a `CTE`

```
with cte as(
select
    CountryID,
    DefaulteCountryID,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by CountryID order by CountryRank) as rn
from DefaultCountries
where DefaultCountryID in (select distinct CountryID from @CountryData))
```

Then just join to this cte `where rn = 1`

So this would satisfy "Basically I want to have something where if there is no records in my table that I'm trying to join to with the 1st record (CountryRank = 1) then I would like it to search for the next record" meaning if there wasn't a 1 you'd get 2, or 3, or what ever the next order number is.

Comment: Only DefaultCountries has a CountryRank the other tables (in my example CountryData ) only have a countryid - when I join where rn = 1 I get no rows.

Comment: @webdad3 so the country rank is null... or...? What other tables?

Comment: I updated my question to identify the table that does not have a CountryRank - Let me know if I need to add more clarification.  This table in my example is a temporary table.  But it represents a physical table that I can't take a screenshot of.

Comment: @webdad3 sorry, i'm still utterly confused. You are trying to join the `DefaultCountries` table to your @CountryData, conditionally it seems. The condition is what I don't understand.

Comment: The CountryData table contains the data I want, however, the DefaultCountries table has the rankings.  So if I pass in the countryid of 7 I really need the countryid of 10 to return so I can get all the records in the CountryData table that have a countryid of 10.  I want to be able to pass in a countryid and have it cycle through my options 7,10,1 (for countryid of 7).  If no 7, then 10, if no 10, then 1 (so on and so forth).  I'm not sure my comments are making it any clearer...  I'm sorry.  I will take a look at my question in a bit to see if I can add or update it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130557/discussion-between-scsimon-and-webdad3).